# Plausible Analytics: How to measure SPA without any path change whatsoever?

Tags: plausible-analytics

I'm installing plausible analytics on an SPA that very rarely changes the URL path, in any way. I've seen [this](https://plausible.io/docs/spa-support) page on SPA's, however it shows steps on how to capture clicks on SPAs only if the URL changes.

Currently, the 'Visit Duration' is unrealistically low. My theory is that this is because most visits are counted as bounces, since the only event fired is the initial event - even if the user stays for 2 hours.

My question is: What's the idiomatic event to tell plausible that the user is still there? Currently my approach is to manually fire a `pageview` event every couple minutes. However, this makes the actual page view count meaningless.

What's the idiomatic way to do this?